# Where do we find the Haman was a Shadchan?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Megilla says "כי המן בן-המדתא האגגי צורר כל היהודים" - Haman found co-wives for all Jews. Implying that he was a Shadchan.

Where do we find his involvement in Shadchanus?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: He was trying to give his doughter instead of vashti

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this definition of the word צורר meaning finding co-wives. Can you edit in a better explanation?

Comment: @DanF Tzarah means a co-wife

Comment: @DanF it's in lev 18 and samuel 1

Comment: OK. I never understood that usage (I guess it' snot that frequent.) My understanding of the verse you cited about Haman, seems to mean that Haman himself was the co-wife of everyone, not that he arranged co-wives. What am I missing, here in how you interpret that he arranged co-wives?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that he was a Shadchan is obvious. A Shadchan [stands](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_50455_180.pdf) for "שקר דובר כסף נוטל" - Says lies and takes money (Haman told Achashverosh lies and took the money he offered Achashveirosh back).

The reason why he's called Tzorer Kol HaYehudim is because, like in Egypt, all the Jews got divorced in anticipation of Haman's decree.

After the decree was lifted, they got remarried, but (unlike in [Egypt](http://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.12a.10/he/Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), the Kohanim couldn't get remarried to their old wives, so they had to marry others.

Due to the [Shidduch crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shidduch_crisis), more and more people had to get married to the same person, resulting in many co-wives.